# How to add and get attributes of html element in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For example I have this code:

```
 <div class="class1" ng-keydown="ex()">
 </div>
```

How do I get all these attributes that are in the div tag? I want to get the class and ng-keydown using jquery for example and how can I add something to this  using jquery, for example,  if I wanted to add ng-mouseclick to this.

Comment: Did you do any research before asking? [jQuery.attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function is not hard to find.

Comment: What is your objective? You just cannot add angular directives using jQuery/javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I get all these attributes that are in the div tag?

Use `attributes` and `reduce`

```
var elem = document.querySelector('div').attributes;
var output  = [...elem].reduce( ( a, c ) => ( a[ c.nodeName ] = c.value, a ) , {});
```

**Demo**

```js
var elem = document.querySelector('div').attributes;
var output  = [...elem].reduce( ( a, c ) => ( a[ c.nodeName ] = c.value, a ) , {});
console.log( output );
```

```html
<div class="class1" ng-keydown="ex()"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get all attributes by `$("div")[0].attributes;` of the one div

```js
//Get All Attributed of div
let attr = $("div")[0].attributes;

//Loop thru all attributes
$.each(attr, function(e) {
  if (this.specified) {
    console.log(this.name + ": " + this.value);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class1" ng-keydown="ex()"></div>
```

---

If you have multiple `divs`, you can do `each` to loop thru the `div`s

```js
$("div").each(function() {
  $.each(this.attributes, function(e) {
    if (this.specified) {
      console.log(this.name + ": " + this.value);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class1" ng-keydown="ex()"></div>
<div class="class2" ng-keydown="ex2()"></div>
<div class="class3" ng-keydown="ex3()"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this: `$('.class1').attr('ng-keydown');`

Comment: Thanks, any way to add an attribute with jquery to this div element and delete a attribute?

Comment: @xander has already answered the question. please look at the comment against your question.

Comment: @DāvisR. You can use angular for that: angular.element(document.querySelector('.class1')).attr('your_attr_key', 'your_attr_value');
and for remove: angular.element(document.querySelector('.class1')).removeAttr('attr_key')

Comment: @zb22 This question is about javascript, jQuery, and html. jQuery can do that just fine with the `attr()` and `removeAttr()` functions. No need to bring in angular.

Comment: @MarkBaijens yes, but because I noticed that the code in the question includes angular (ng-keydown), it's recommended to use angular for such purposes.